# Switching (and even getting list of) contexts crashes Appium

Tags: ios-simulator, appium

Software: Appium 1.3.6, iOS Simulator with iOS 8.2, Java code.

The simple scenario:
Clicking 'Login with Google' in our app -> A webview is opened (google login)

I need to input email|pass and click 'login' in webview. And here comes the trouble. Calling driver.getContextHandles(); (to find the webview and switch to it) causes Appium to crash.

The error: [REMOTE] Could not connect to WebKitRemoteDebugger server

What do I miss here? Is there a way to overcome this? Maybe you've done something similar?

Comment: its good if you mention your code here

Comment: As simple as that: Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles();
  for (String string : contexts){
   System.out.println(string);
  }

Answer (score 1):

To work with web contexts on iOS you have to run `ios_webkit_debug_proxy_server` with port `27753`.
**To install:** `brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy`
You can run it as standalone utility:

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c UDID:27753
```

I recommend to run JS from Appium source code:

```
node appium/bin/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js -c UDID:27753
```

**See:** https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/bin/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem. Everything is also in Appium documentation, section Advanced Concepts->iOS WebKit Debug Proxy. http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#ios-webkit-debug-proxy